# Touch not working on the view which have set onclick listener in listview.

Tags: android, android-listview, onclick, swipe, swipe-gesture

I am trying to implement the listview with swipe to delete and undo in my project. it works fine.code for demo is [Here.](http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2013/09/remove-and-undo-listview-item-with.html)

But  my need is to handle click event for each view, each view have some action to perform.

[image]

According to this image, view which one is in middle(data 1, data 2) have a clickListener, when i swipe from right to left by put the finger  on lastview(yellow or grey round) it detect the swipe but when i try to swipe from middle Textview (data 1, data 2) it not allow me to swipe from textview(data 1 , data 2).

my need is to start swipe from any where in list row and also handle click of each view (inside row like edittext, Textview and Imageview).

Can anybody help me to come out from this?

Comment: Post some code which can be understandable. The link which you have provided is sufficient to provide you solution.

Comment: @Yog Guru Hey did you solved your problem. I am also stuck with the same problem. Please help me out. I want to implement Swipe gesture on my ListView along with onClick on its items (textview, imageview...). Here is the link to my SO question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32866357/swipelistener-on-listview-and-clicklistener-on-listviews-items      When I start the swipe from the TextView the ListView's swipe gestures never detects it. However, if I swipe the ListView from empty space, the swipe gesture detects.

Comment: @NiteshKhatri No, not get the solution for this. I was switch to another ui related this due to this problem. :(

Answer (score 0):

all you need is a some research about ViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvent() method